# AndroidStudio (IDEA) code inspection: "... may produce NullPointerException"

Tags: java, android

I have following piece of code in Java:

```
String func() {
    Object data = otherFunc();
    return data.toString();
}
```

The otherFunc() is @Nullable function and it can return null. So the IDE highlights toString() method as dangerous, because it can cause NullPointerException.

But in my case, I'm 100% confident about not-null result of otherFunc(). So I added an assert condition there:

```
String func() {
    Object data = otherFunc();
    MyAssert.notNull(data, some_debug_info);
    return data.toString();
}
```

There is a null-check verification inside the MyAssert.notNull() call and throwing an exception (with some additional debug info) if it's null.
Android Studio highlights toString() anyway...

**Question:**

How can I indicate that "data" object can't be null after the MyAssert.notNull() call? Maybe with some @annotations?

There are many similar places in the code, so the solution should modify the assert function only!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IntelliJ's `Contract` annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/contract-annotations.html) might be what you're looking for.

Annotating your method with `@Contract("null, _ -> fail")` should tell intelliJ that entering null as the first parameter would cause an exception, meaning any code after the call will assume it is non-null.